# Mysql/Grails: How entity ID is being initialized upon calling Entity.save() (without flushing) on a newly created entity?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm using Mysql and Grails.

Suppose I have an entity class `Book`, `book` table in mysql has an `auto_incremented` `id` column.

Say the following is my service method:

```
@Transactional
public void someMethod() {
    Book book = new Book("Book Name", "Author Name") // book.id is null here 
    book.save();
    println book.id // id is initialized
}
```

When I stop on `println` statement using debugger I see that `book`'s `id` property is initialized. As I'm not `flushing` anything to db the row is not inserted into db yet and hence the `id` is not generated upon insertion, but some other way. One possible way the `id` might be initialized seems to be that hibernate runs a query just for fetching the next `auto_increment` value when the `save()` method is executed on entity (not sure if it's the case).  If it's the case then what about 2 concurrent transactions getting the same ID ??

Comment: Doesn't `@Transactional` write to the database on `.save()`?  If the transaction is rolled back, the next record will still get a different ID even though this one was never used (as far as you can tell from looking at the database -- it will have been skipped).

Comment: @Transactional ensures that transaction will be committed when the method completes, so in the described case, as we are still inside the method, transaction is not committed yet

Comment: Right -- but not committed != not inserted.  That's the idea of database transactions, you can make changes to the database -- including inserting rows so that you have their auto increment PK value -- before actually committing the changes. Fetching the next auto increment value would be hopelessly naïve, for the reason you indicated.  I am a DBA, not familiar with grails, but I can't imagine it's doing anything other than doing the insert here -- which is safe to do, since it's inside a transaction that can be rolled back implicitly by MySQL if an exception is thrown before commit.

Comment: In case of `book.save(flush: true)` the insert statement will be flushed to db in contrast to `book.save()`.  In the latter case hibernate will execute 'flush' just before transaction commit which will be after the method finishes its execution. That's why i have mentioned `without flushing` in my question as in case of `book.save(flush: true)` it is obvious that the statement will be flushed and executed in db returning the autoincremented `id`

Comment: Temporarily turn on the MySQL [General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html) which logs all queries as they are issued, with timestamps and the id of the thread that ran the query.   Add some sleep statements between each line in your code and observe what is actually happening at the database.

Comment: That's an option that I can do later :)